# Enriching html as part of gulp

Tags: angularjs, gulp, template-engine

We are using angularjs on client side. We want to inject or enrich html in partials on server side as part of build. We are using gulp for build. Any idea what is the best way. Will using any standard template engine will be overkill. Will parsing html is better or simple gulp inject is best.

Comment: Without any further details, [`gulp-inject`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject) sounds like it'll do the job just fine.

Comment: @Hue thanks. Actually my application mainly consists of more than thousand of forms. So we were thinking of a visual tool to drag drop controls. I have seen many tools are keeping the meta data in xml or json. I some how prefer writing html using text editors rather than drag drop tool. So I wanted my framework to support both. Whatever Css or angular bindings or validation directive we want to add based on business type of field I was suggesting as part of gulp build. So I was preferring something like simple raw html plus some framework equal to actual HTML as generated.

Comment: And i wanted my framework to support handwritten HTML as well as HTML produced by visual tool  as far as input HTML which acts like meta data. It gives me some flexibility to upgrade angular version or switch from angular to something.